# storm - how to choose a stream grouping

Tags: apache-storm

I'm using the `KafkaSpout` to read / stream message of compressed Byte[]. The bolts are simple: uncompress the message -> write to Cassandra. I'm wondering which **Stream Grouping** to use.

The samples appear to mainly use the **Shuffle Grouping**. In testing I've been using the **All Grouping** (figuring that I want all of the messages to go through the one bolt) but I see notes about "Use this grouping with care".

Suggestions on how to proceeed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shuffle grouping is sufficient for your use case, which distributes workload across downstream bolts.

All grouping is rarely needed, and can results in duplicated processing in all downstream bolts.

Reference:
https://storm.apache.org/documentation/Concepts.html#stream-groupings